Excising the trace of a $II_1$-factor
Recall that a state $\varphi$ on a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is said to be excised by projections if there exists a net of projections $e_i \in A$ such that $\| e_i a e_i - \varphi(a) e_i\| \to_{i} 0$ for all $a \in A$.
This is Definition 11.4.1 in Brown and Ozawa's book on approximation properties of $C^*$-algebras.
Given a $II_1$-factor $(M,\tau)$, Brown and Ozawa show that the trace $\tau$ is excised by projections, as a state on $M$. Indeed, Proposition 11.4.2. in the book shows that in general, every state on a simple, unital, infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra of real rank zero can be excised by projections. The proof involves both Glimm's lemma (Lemma 1.4.11) and the Ackermann-Anderson-Pedersen excision theorem.
My question is can one show that the trace on a $II_1$-factor is excised by projections, without appealing to the $C^*$-algebraic techniques mentioned above?
I was wondering about a simpler proof in the case of $II_1$-factors, as this is one of the ingredients that go into the proof of injectivity implying hyperfinitness presented in that book. $II_1$ factors have a relatively well understood structure of projections when compared to general $C^*$-algebras, so one could think that a simpler proof should exist in this case.
Any references/comments would be much appreciated.
